# How to increment index column by one in csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning

I have my predictions for 10000 classes, I could save it to csv (python), but it saved my class predictions like from 0 to 9999 (when I open this file in Excel), but I need from 1 to 10000

How can I change it?

```
import pandas as pd
prediction = pd.DataFrame(to_save.T).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

Comment: to_save - numpy.ndarray

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ If your comment is part of your question then please edit your post and include it _ thanks : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the index before saving like this

```
import pandas as pd
prediction = pd.DataFrame(to_save.T)
prediction.index += 1
prediction.to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your fdataframe "df" with the command: `df.to_csv(path,index=False)`